# GCM sends different RegistrationId everytime

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am having a little "problem" with the `GCM` service of Android.
The point is that, every time I ask for a registration_id, the `GCM` server returns a **different registration_id**. The worst is that, after doing tests, both the old ones and the new ones are working properly!! (I send a PUSH message to the old ones and to the new ones and my app is receiving the push from every of them!!).

This is the `AsyncTask` I am using the register in the `GCM` Android server:

```
public class AltaGCM extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        int contador = 0;
        try{
           regId = gcm.register(CrisolGooglePlayServicesUtils.SENDER_ID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            statusCode = -1;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listener.respuestaGCM(statusCode, regId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but, this is happening to me since 2 months (more or less). Before I never had this problem, `GCM` server used to return me the **SAME registration_id** (not every times, but sometimes).......

I don't know if to receive every time a **different registration_id** is normal or if it is something wrong I am doing.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [GCM registering with two different working registration ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908886/gcm-registering-with-two-different-working-registration-ids?rq=1)

Look at the answer provided by @nunofmendes

> Sometimes Google changes the registration ID and you'll have multiple
>   IDs associated. The server that sends the notification (your server)
>   has to update the database with the new ID.
>
> For more info check this document:
>
> http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html
>
> That says:
>
> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well,
>   everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application
>   triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to
>   reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

Comment: According to that doc, it is happening because of a "bug" on the "application". Well, I don't know what's the problem, if it is happening because of the client part (I think I am doing the registration correctly...that's my point), or is it happening in the Application on the Google API Console?

Comment: The point is that I know what the Android documentation says about it, but what I don't understand is what "On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well, everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device" means. Cause it seems to be like a problem on the Android app.....is it correct? In that case, What's the problem? Cause I am using the latest Google Play Services and the latest documentation to do it..so I don't understand