# GCM 3.0: New registration does not expire tokens registered with GCMRegistrar

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We are switching our notifications infrastructure to use new GCM 3.0 registration mechanism using Instance ID API. Previously we were using old mechanism using GCMRegistrar.register() method.

The problem we have is that we have noticed that if device was registered with old GCMRegistrar, after update and registering with new Instance ID API, both registration tokens are valid and can receive notifications.

I expected old registration token to be deactivated and that our push server would receive canonical registration ID when sending notification to old token (as described here [GCM registering with two different working registration ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908886/gcm-registering-with-two-different-working-registration-ids)), especially that application version has changed, but such case seems not to happen.

Is this correct behavior of GCM? Is there any way we can detect on push server that device received new token (without unregistering from app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally received an answer from Google support regarding my issue. It turned out that this was intended behavior:

> What you observed is in the intended behavior due to the need to support backward compatible
>   registration ID.
>
> We recommend you to flag the old registration ID from gcmregistrar() and don't use that to send anymore once you have the registration token from getToken(). (I believe you probably has implemented a solution to detect such)

Our solution was to simply remove old registration tokens from our push server before registering new user.

We did not use GCMRegistrar.unregister() as we observed that it was able to unregister new tokens (obtained via getToken()).

**UPDATE:**

I just wanted to provide a quick update to anyone interested in this subject.

It seems that this issue was fixed as when we tested our registration mechanism recently, it turned out that new GCM tokens replace (and unregister) old tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Registration token may change upon certain scenarios even going forward. While cononical registration ID is also a good idea. Use `tokenRefresh` as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) as well.

```js
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Suggesting based on this line **"it is needed for key rotation and to handle special cases"** in [method reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService#public-methods).

Comment: We already handle token refreshes. Our problem is that old token already registered for same device (with deprecated GCMRegistrar.register()) is not being invalidated when we register new token with Instance ID API. When our notification server sends messages to both tokens we have no information that one of the tokens is not valid anymore. From Google documentation I would expect that we should receive a new canonical ID for old token.